# Why do I get this strange floating list of services instead of win 7 Task Manager?

Tags: windows-7, task-manager

If I open Task Manager (from the `ctrl-alt-delete` screen or from `ctrl-shift-escape`), instead of the usual window, I currently get this strange floating list with none of the usual controls, and no apparent way to close it:

[image]

It appears to be a list of "Services", judging by the fact that right-clicking on any gives the options `Start service`, `Stop service` and `Go to process`. But strangely there's a `Services` button that goes to another window of services. Unlike the task manager I'm used to, it shows everything including things that aren't running.

Right-clicking on the window itself does nothing.

What I want is the normal list of running applications where I can force things to close.

What is this window, why am I getting it instead of the task manager, and how can I get the normal task manager back?

Comment: While the linked duplicate is about Vista and shows a different-looking window, the answer does answer this question.